# Indent If statement in algoritmic package

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

I have the below code and I'm trying to indent the IF statement to be exactly below statement 5.
I would be grateful if you can help me solve this issue. Thanks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]
{               
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE {Input}: statement 1
\STATE statement 2
\FOR {statement 3}
\STATE statement 4
\STATE \hspace{.5cm} statement 5
\IF{statement 6}
\STATE statement 7
\ELSE
\STATE statement 9
\ENDIF
\STATE statement 10
\ENDFOR         
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{title}
}                       
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following example, a new pair of commands, `\SCOPE` and `\ENDSCOPE`, is defined. Contents in between `\SCOPE` and `\ENDSCOPE` will have an extra level of indentation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
% defined only inside "algorithmic" environment
\xpatchcmd\algorithmic
  {\newcommand{\IF}}
  {%
    \newcommand\SCOPE{\begin{ALC@g}}%
    \newcommand\ENDSCOPE{\end{ALC@g}}%
    \newcommand{\IF}%
  }
  {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[t]  
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE {Input}: statement 1
    \STATE statement 2
    \FOR {statement 3}
      \STATE statement 4
      \SCOPE    % <<< new command
        \STATE statement 5
        \IF{statement 6}
          \STATE statement 7
        \ELSE
          \STATE statement 9
        \ENDIF
      \ENDSCOPE % <<< new command
      \STATE statement 10
    \ENDFOR
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{title}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `ALC@g`? Is there an easy way to do this when using only the `\usepackage{algorithm}` package? E.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689638/144086

Comment: @rrrrr 1) `ALC@g` is an internal environment from `algorithmic` package. Its content is typeset with an extra indent level.  The `\FOR` body, `\IF` true-branch and `\ELSE` false-branch are all nested in an `ALC@g` env. `algorithmic` provides little customization ways hence I have to use some of its internal info.  2) No it's impossible. `algorithm` package only provides a float environment `algorithm`, and  it's `algorithmic` or `algpseudocode` package which provides pseudo-code markup environment and commands.