# How to manually (further) indent an `if` statement in `algorithm`

Tags: indentation, algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

For example, I would like to further indent an `if-then-else` block like is done in this [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553651/144086).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{my alg}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \If{condition} % <-- would like to indent this whole block further
      \State{$x=1$}
    \EndIf
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define an "empty" block to create a new nesting level.

The new block should have no text and produce not extra lines.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\algblockdefx{Nest}{EndNest}{}{}
\algtext*{Nest}{}
\algtext*{EndNest}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{my alg}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \If{condition} % <-- would like to indent this whole block further
            \State{$x=1$}
        \EndIf
        \Statex
        \Nest
            \If{condition} % <-- would like to indent this whole block further
                \State{$x=1$}
            \EndIf
        \EndNest
        \Statex
        \Nest
            \Nest
                \If{condition} % <-- would like to indent this whole block further
                    \State{$x=1$}
                \EndIf
            \EndNest
        \EndNest
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```